# Как убрать ошибку 500 из-за .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день!
подскажите пожалуйста, после переноса сайта на другой хостинг, появилась маленькая проблемка

Есть папка mysite.jp/backend - админка, в ней есть файл .htaccess

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

По факту этот .htaccess преобразовывает url 
(добавляется знак вопроса после mysite.jp/backend/)

> mysite.jp/backend/users/girls/menu/100010 в
>
> mysite.jp/backend/?users/girls/menu/100010

Но с этим файлом нельзя залогиниться в админку по адрессу

> mysite.jp/backend/index/login

в дебагере хрома показывает 500 ошибку

Без .htaccess - нормально логиниться,
но ссылки в админке не преобразовываются - соответственно не происходит перехода.
Если руками добавлять знак ? к URL в браузере - то ссылка начинает работает

Помогите пожалуйста, добавить исключение в .htaccess - чтобы он пропускал процесс логина

Заранее Спасибо!

ps. Не знаю на сколько это принципиально, в главной директории сайта есть такие строки в .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=permanent]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: *показывает 500 ошибку* — в `error.log` апача что при этом записывается?

Comment: `PHP Warning:  require(main.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/admin/web/mysite.jp/public_html/backend/index.php on line 12`


`PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'main.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/admin/web/mysite.jp/public_html/backend/index.php on line 12`

**Файл backend/index.php**

`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/backend/index' AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/backend/index/login') {
  require "../main.php";
 } else {
  require "main.php";
 }
`
**12 строчка - require "main.php";**

Comment: main.php находится в корне папки сайта /home/admin/web/mysite.jp/public_html/

Comment: понятно, в эту сторону копать не стоит. сейчас добавлю ответ.

Comment: ****many thx)****

Comment: я ещё раз обновил ответ. перечитываю вопрос и не могу понять: при наличии вашего варианта файла `/backend/.htaccess` вообще хоть как-то залогиниться можно? если возможно, то все остальные функции сайта (включая работу в «админке») выполняются нормально?

Comment: Александр, спасибо Вам большое за внимание! Последний Ваш вариант пробывал - особо ничего не поменялось. И так нормально работает - с Вашей помощью!

Comment: Интересно - почему возникла эта проблема? Из-за того что поменялся хостинг?

Comment: *Из-за того что поменялся хостинг?* — возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

после обсуждений и попыток воссоздать ситуацию пришёл к такому варианту:

```
RewriteEngine On

rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/index/
rewriterule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

отличается от вашего варианта двумя добавленными строчками.

Comment: добавил - теперь по ссылке логина **http://mysite.jp/backend/index/login** ошибка 404

Comment: а если сейчас «добавить знак вопроса»? (в какую, кстати, позицию вы его вписываете?)

Comment: ооо! сейчас немного криво но работает если добавлять ?login.

Comment: сейчас попробую описать ситуацию. **Спасибо Вам ОГРОМНОЕ!**

Comment: в смысле «добавлять ?login»? какой конкретно url рабочий?

Comment: **http://my.site/backend/index/login** -404.
**http://my.site/backend/?index/login** -появляется форма для логина. После ввода логина идет редирект
**http://my.site/backend/index** -500.
**http://my.site/backend/?index** -уже все работает

Comment: это сейчас такой порядок чтоб зайти

Comment: ну, безопасность на высшем уровне: фиг залогинишься. наводящий вопрос. вы пишете, что правила из файла `/backend/.htaccess` преобразуют `/backend/users/...` в `/backend/?users/...`, хотя, насколько я понимаю, на самом деле они преобразуют `/backend/что-угодно` в `/backend/index.php?/backend/что-угодно`. я, видимо, чего-то не допонимаю?

Comment: я не могу Вам точно ответить, мне кажеться что ? добавляет .htaccess из корня, я его в конце старта топика публиковал

Comment: нет, `.htaccess` из корня перенаправляет все запросы (не к файлам и не к каталогам) на обработку файлу `index.php`.

Comment: я добавил ещё один «костыль» в ответ. проверьте, что после этого будет происходить.

Comment: в новом варианте окно логина открывается по предыдущей схеме, но редиректа на залогиненый сайт не происходит. после кнопки нажатия логин - ничего не происходит, остаемся на странице логина

Comment: внёс ещё одну поправку в ответ и убрал про дополнительные строки — они, судя по всему, лишние.

Comment: напишите, как после этого происходит логин, приходится ли что-то изменять в url.

Comment: к сожалению все также, как и работало. только сейчас выход из логина  не работает без добавления в ручную вопроса backend/index/exit/menu/99999

Comment: т.е., сейчас вы добавили в свой файл только одну предложенную мной строку (обратите внимание: она изменилась по сравнению с первым вариантом)?

Comment: да, rewritecond поменял, rewriterule - убрал